# Reading cookies from a master domain?

Tags: cookies

I have a login system that store the cookie in the master domain and I want to read it from a subdomain. I don't know how to read it from the master domain. Here's what my situation looks like. [The cookie is on the master domain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myft4.png) I don't care if it's in PHP or JavaScript, either'll work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, after playgrounding-around, I got it to work by this. Apparently works even from the master domain.

`<?php echo $_COOKIE['username'] ?>`